# Scaling Bitmaps Without Throwing Quality

Tags: android, bitmap, fullscreen

I have created an app that actually uses flood fill algorithm to fill colors in bitmaps. I have created some bitmaps (200x200) but I don't know the exact size of bitmap that I should create, I want bitmaps to cover full screen and when I scale bitmaps, they become blur and flood fill doesn't work on them. I saw an app that used GridView to show images and click on image started new activity with image covering full screen. How can I achieve this. Attached is CustomImage that I've use to show bitmap. Any help will be appreciated. 
**EDITED:** I know that GridView doesn't scale up image to full screen, it use another image. That app behaves same for different screen size, those image fill screen of any size without effecting the quality.

public class CustomImage extends View {

```
public CustomImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
} // end constructor

public CustomImage(Context context, int resource_id) {
    super(context);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPoint = new Point();
    mProgressIndicator = (ProgressIndicator) context;
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource_id)
            .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

} // end constructor

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw image
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
} // end onDraw

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int bWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
    int bHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();

    mPoint.x = (int) event.getX();
    mPoint.y = (int) event.getY();

    mPoint.x = (mPoint.x > bWidth) ? (bWidth - 5) : mPoint.x;
    mPoint.y = (mPoint.y > bHeight) ? (bHeight - 5) : mPoint.y;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    // called when screen clicked i.e New touch started
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mProgressIndicator.updateProgress(0);
        new Filler(mBitmap, mPoint, mPaint.getColor(), mBitmap.getPixel(
                mPoint.x, mPoint.y), this).execute();
        invalidate();
    } // end Case
    return true;
} // end onTouchEvent

public void setColor(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
} // end setColor
```

} // end Class

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` you have seen might be using two versions of the same image. One as a big image and another as a scaled down thumbnail image for the grid.

Comment: Yes, they use thumbnail but in new activity big image covers full screen. I am talking about that image, how that image is scaled to full screen size without loosing quality.

Comment: intrepidkarthi is suggesting that the image from the GridView isn't scaled up at all. The GridView is displaying only a small thumbnail derived from the full-size bitmap: the full-size version is displayed after its thumbnail is selected from the grid.

Comment: How that full-size image fits into every screen size ?

Comment: you have to set the layout width, height to match parent size.

Comment: Show your layout xml file

Comment: add your complete xml in the question itself

Comment: I cannot paste whole file its too long, but this is the layout for CustomImage <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: where is your code to add `ImageView` to the `layout`?

Comment: mCustomImage = new CustomImage(this, R.drawable.dog);
  mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.image);
  mRelativeLayout.addView(mCustomImage);

Comment: are you sure your `RelativeLayout` covers the whole layout height and width? Set `LayoutParams` for your `CustomImageView` to match its parent. You can do it inside the constructor